# Query WHERE NOT IN (SELECT) INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    SUM(m_out) AS totalOut
FROM
    m_detal
WHERE
    opers = '25'
        AND (m_type = 'Out'
        OR m_type = 'Merged')
        AND m_date <= '2018-11-28 07:30:00'
        AND mark_delete IS NULL
        AND m_ids NOT IN (SELECT 
            m.m_ids
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                m_ids
            FROM
                m_detal
            WHERE
                opers = '25'
                    AND (m_type = 'Out'
                    OR m_type = 'Merged')
                    AND (m_onhold != 'onhold'
                    OR m_onhold IS NULL)
                    AND mark_delete IS NULL
                    AND m_date <= '2018-11-28 07:30:00') AS m
                INNER JOIN
            n_combine_tbl AS t ON (t.comb_id1 = m.m_ids
                OR t.comb_id2 = m.m_ids)
                AND t.time <= '2018-11-28 07:30:00');
```

This query took me more than 30sec or more! The query inside the NOT IN is little bit huge around 7-9k of ids. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I think the inner join part is make it slow where the checking the two column of n_combine_tables which is (comb_id1 or comb_id2).

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: nope my query dont have syntax error. able to query out all the data

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove duplicated conditions in sub-queries and do something like this (two NOT in could be replaced with UNION):

```
SELECT
    SUM(m.m_out) AS totalOut
FROM
    m_detal AS m
WHERE
        m.opers = '25'
    AND m.m_type IN ('Out', 'Merged')
    AND m.m_date <= '2018-11-28 07:30:00'
    AND m.mark_delete IS NULL
    AND m.m_onhold = 'onhold'
    AND m.m_ids NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            t1.comb_id1
        FROM
            n_combine_tbl AS t1
        WHERE
            t1.time <= '2018-11-28 07:30:00'
    )
    AND m.m_ids NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            t2.comb_id2
        FROM
            n_combine_tbl AS t2
        WHERE
            t2.time <= '2018-11-28 07:30:00'
    )
;
```

OR with NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT
    SUM(m.m_out) AS totalOut
FROM
    m_detal AS m
WHERE
        m.opers = '25'
    AND m.m_type IN ('Out', 'Merged')
    AND m.m_date <= '2018-11-28 07:30:00'
    AND m.mark_delete IS NULL
    AND m.m_onhold = 'onhold'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            n_combine_tbl AS t
        WHERE
                t.time <= '2018-11-28 07:30:00'
            AND (
                   t.comb_id1 = m.m_ids
                OR t.comb_id2 = m.m_ids
            )
    )
;
```

1. You should check the 'onhold' logic.
2. You should try to add indexes on n_combine_tbl: (time, comb_id1), (time, comb_id2), (comb_id1, time), (comb_id2, time) and check what is good for your data.
3. Multi-column indexes on m_detal table should also be considered.

Comment: let me add some replacement for your query. for the 'onhold', it should be replace the AND m.m_onhold = 'onhold' with AND (m.m_onhold != 'onhold' or m.m_onhold IS NULL) then the query should world. else it return null... let me giv a summary for those 3 query query time include the original query.. Original query takes18.359sec, for the UNION query it takes 24.457sec and the NOT EXIST query takes 15.922sec.

Comment: "AND m.m_onhold = 'onhold' with AND (m.m_onhold != 'onhold' or m.m_onhold IS NULL)" this makes no sense as it would always be false. You should show execution plan (explain) and information about indexes on both tables. Your query execution times do not look reliable as you said that original query took 30 secs in OP and 18 secs in your comment. You should measure times in similar conditions and use SQL_NO_CACHE hint.

Comment: but t.comb_id1 = m.m_ids OR t.comb_id2 = m.m_ids still concern. Because m.m_ids total row is around 8-9k rows. and it need to check at two column t.comb_id1 or t.comb_id2 whether it exist in the those two column.

Comment: I would not design my database like this. However, the database is in this shape right now and you have to deal with it somehow. Stop guessing! You cannot be certain what is causing slowness without explain information! BTW, have you tried to add suggested indexes?

Comment: not guessing but when i remove the OR the query is fast